# How do I create the current date (or any date) as an NSDate without hours, minutes and seconds?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdate

I need to create an `NSDate` of the current date (or on any NSDate) without the hours, minutes and seconds and keep it as an `NSDate`, in as few lines of as possible?

I need to perform some calculations on dates and having hours, minutes and seconds cause problems, I need absolute dates (I hope absolute is the right phrase). Its for an iPhone app.

I'm creating dates with `[NSDate date]` which add hours, minutes and seconds. Also I'm adding months to dates which I think caters for day light savings as I get 2300 hours on some dates.

So ideally I need a function to create absolute NSDates from NSDates.

I know I asked a similar question earlier, but I need to end up with NSDate not a string and I'm a little concerned about specifying a date format e.g. yyyy etc.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

First, you have to understand that even if you strip hours, minutes and seconds from an `NSDate`, it will still represent a single moment in time. You will never get an `NSDate` to represent an entire day like `2011-01-28`; it will always be `2011-01-28 00:00:00 +00:00`. That implies that you have to take time zones into account, as well.

Here is a method (to be implemented as an `NSDate` category) that returns an `NSDate` at midnight UTC on the same day as `self`:

```
- (NSDate *)midnightUTC {
    NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    [calendar setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];

    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit
                                                   fromDate:self];
    [dateComponents setHour:0];
    [dateComponents setMinute:0];
    [dateComponents setSecond:0];

    NSDate *midnightUTC = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComponents];
    [calendar release];

    return midnightUTC;
}
```

Comment: Always Ole, beating me to the answer! ;( 

Good answer, as always.

Comment: You don't need to add `[dateComponents setHour:0];[dateComponents setMinute:0];[dateComponents setSecond:0];` since you don't have this components in the dateComponents var, the NSDate will be created at `00:00:00 +0000`.

Answer (score 2):

```
NSDate *oldDate = [NSDate date];
NSCalendarUnit requiredDateComponents = NSYearCalendarUnit| NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit;    
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:requiredDateComponents fromDate:oldDate]; 
NSDate *newDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:components];
```