# How can I create a date with no hours in the current time zone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

This question follows on from a previous question...

[How do I create the current date (or any date) as an NSDate without hours, minutes and seconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4832536/how-do-i-create-the-current-date-or-any-date-as-an-nsdate-without-hours-minute)

I would use this code as follows...

```
NSDate *todaysDate = [General makeAbsoluteNSDate:[NSDate date]];
```

My problem is that I have users in different countries and UTC isn't their timezone and the date produced by this function at certain times of the day won't be correct.

How do I get the current time zone to correct my function ?
Or should I be using a different approach ?

Heres the function I've been using...

```
+ (NSDate *)makeAbsoluteNSDate:(NSDate*)datSource {

NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:
      NSGregorianCalendar];
[calendar setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];

NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit | 
                  NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit
                  fromDate:datSource];
[dateComponents setHour:0];
[dateComponents setMinute:0];
[dateComponents setSecond:0];

NSDate *midnightUTC = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComponents];
[calendar release];

return midnightUTC;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the timezone object from this call:

```
[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]
```

And you can use the **[secondsFromGMT](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimeZone_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTimeZone/secondsFromGMT)** method to figure out the difference and create a date with the timezone.

You can even build a Category for NSDate that includes a method to transform a date into the current timezone date, which would be even simpler.

Comment: Thanks, wouldn't I just need to use localTimeZone in this scenario ?

Comment: Well, you have to get a date and transform it to something else, I'd say just calculating the difference between the two of them is surely simpler than creating a NSCalendar, but that's just taste, as long as it solves your problem that's good enough for me :)